# How show Image on axis value of flutter graph

Tags: flutter, graph, stacked-chart

I want to set an image on the index of the Stacked Graph of a flutter on the x-axis.

[image]

I created a graph class for this. but I don't know how to add an image on the index of the x-axis like in the picture.

I used (https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/example) this package for graph implementation.

**CustomChart.dart**

```
import 'package:climate_karma/utils/values/constant_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

import '../model/chartData.dart';

class CustomChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomChart> createState() => _CustomChartState();
}

class _CustomChartState extends State<CustomChart> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:  Container(
          height: 150,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 48,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                            child: Icon(Icons.electric_car,size: 30),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                            child: Icon(Icons.electric_car,size: 30,),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: SfCartesianChart(
                          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                           isVisible: false,
                            
                            interval: 1,
                          ),
                          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(interval: 1,maximum: 6),
                         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          series: <ChartSeries>[
                            StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: ChartData.chartDataList,
                                color: ConstantColors.greenVoilrtColor,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.index
                            ),
                            StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: ChartData.chartDataList,
                                color: ConstantColors.orengeColor,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) =>data.index,
                            ),
                            StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: ChartData.chartDataList,
                                color: ConstantColors.yellowColor,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.index
                            ),
                            StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: ChartData.chartDataList,
                                color: ConstantColors.zestColor,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.index
                            ),
                            StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: ChartData.chartDataList,
                                color: ConstantColors.bianchiGreenColor,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.index
                            )
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                )
            )

    );
  }
}
```

CharData.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChartData{
  String name;
  String image;
  Widget material;

  num index;
  ChartData({required this.index,required this.name, required this.image,required this.material});

 static List<ChartData> chartDataList = [
   ChartData(index: 0,name: "elec", image: "assets/images/icon_power.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")) ,
   ChartData(index: 1.3,name: "elec", image: "assets/images/icon_transport.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),
   ChartData(index: 1.3,name: "elec", image: "assets/images/icon_power.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),
   ChartData(index: 1.5,name: "elec", image: "assets/images/icon_power.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),
   ChartData(index: 1.6,name: "elec", image: "assets/images/icon_power.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),
   ChartData(index: 4,name: "fuel", image: "assets/images/icon_power.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),
   ChartData(index: 5,name: "fuel", image: "assets/images/icon_transport.svg",material: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/icon_power.svg")),

  ];

}
```

Comment: Did you manage to implement this one?

Comment: yes, I implemented this but not efficiently within the package. I use stack for this.